# Essay in a sci-fi anthology; A missile from (circa) 1968 is found in 1940 - When do scientists think it's from?

Tags: story-identification, technology

This was more of an essay in a collection of sci-fi stories (e.g. rather than an actual story) that I read maybe in the late 1960's.

The premise was that given the tech that they had in 1940(ish) that they would not be able to register the pulses in a solid state circuit board, that they didn't have the manufacturing tech to make the magnesium casing, etc.

The bottom line was that scientists would guess that the missile was from 1000 years into the future rather than merely 20-30 years ahead.

Comment: Leaders in a field will know where the bleeding edge lives.  Some will know how to recognize the handiwork of other greats.  Various companies have their own flavors of "cool-aid".  A systematic analysis of a 1960's era missile (not ICBM-nuke, but air-to-air, for example) might allow inference that it was near future instead of far future.  They might see english-language marks, hex nuts, and some known alloys as well as unknown.  Were I a 3-letter organization, I would use this for handling other-nation devices (satellite falls vs. ufo).

Comment: According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor) Wiki article on transistors, Physicist Julius Edgar Lilienfeld filed patents on field effect transistors in the U.S. in 1926 (1925 in Canada). So at least the theoretical basis for semiconductors was known in the 1940's. I'm not sure what you mean by "registering the pulses" in a "solid-state circuit board", but I've worked on some pretty old-school electronics (microfilm cameras, to be specific. Some even *had* tubes!) and there was nothing any competent technician couldn't figure out with a 1940's voltmeter and oscilloscope.

Comment: I'm going from a 35 year old memory here so the specifics might be wobbly.  Thats not really the issue though.  The question is whether this sort of essay rings any bells.

Answer (score 19):

That sounds like ["No Copying Allowed"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?66716), an editorial by [John W. Campbell, Jr.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_W._Campbell) in the [November 1948 *Astounding Science Fiction*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57621). The full text is available at the [Internet Archive](http://archive.org/stream/collectededitori01camp#page/60/mode/2up).

**This was more of an essay in a collection of sci-fi stories (e.g. rather than an actual story) that I read maybe in the late 1960's.**

That editorial was reprinted in a 1966 book called [*Collected Editorials from Analog*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?292986) by John W. Campbell (selected by [Harry Harrison](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?28)); the whole book is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/collectededitori01camp). As far as I know, that's the only place you could have read it in the late 1960s, outside of an old copy of the November 1948 *Astounding*. Of course, that's a collection of essays, not a collection of sci-fi stories. It also appeared in [*Turning Points: Essays on the Art of Science Fiction*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?52500), a 1977 non-fiction anthology edited by [Damon Knight](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?633).  However, if you really read it in a collection of sci-fi **stories**, the earliest possibility that the ISFDB knows of is [Stanley Schmidt](http://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/schmidt_stanley)'s 1980 [*Analog Anthology #1*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?35157), also published as [*Analog's Golden Anniversary Anthology*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?35156) and [*Fifty Years of the Best Science Fiction from Analog*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?191073).

**A missile from (circa) 1968 is found in 1940**

The scenario is set 20 years earlier than that:

> Let's first consider this situation: Time: About 1920. Place: An
> American Army Air Base. Action: High overhead a small airplane tears across the sky with a high, thin whistle. Ground observers, after tracking it for a minute or so—during which time
> it has passed out of sight—report incredulously that it was doing
> between nine hundred fifty and one thousand miles per hour.
> It circles back, slows abruptly as the whistle dies out, and makes
> a hot, deadstick landing. Investigators reach the cornfield where
> it landed, and find it ninety percent intact—and one hundred
> percent impossible. Swept-back wings, no tail, automatic control
> equipment of incredibly advanced design, are all understandable
> in so far as function intended goes. But the metal alloys used
> make no sense to the metallurgists when they go to work on them.
> The "engine," moreover, is simply, starkly insane. The only indication of anything that might remotely be considered an engine
> is a single, open tube—really open; open at both ends. But the
> empty fuel tank had tubes leading into some sort of small jets in
> that pipe. The athodyd being unheard of in 1920, the thing is
> senseless. Filling the fuel tanks simply causes a hot fire that must
> be extinguished quickly to prevent burning out the tube. The fact
> that this is a guided missile intended for launching from a four-hundred-mile-an-hour bomber makes the situation a little difficult
> for the 1920 technologists; the athodyd won't start functioning
> below two hundred fifty m.p.h., and nothing on Earth could reach
> that speed in 1920.

**The bottom line was that scientists would guess that the missile was from 1000 years into the future rather than merely 20-30 years ahead.**

> In summary, the aerodynamicists report that the tailless monstrosity is interesting, but the principles of its design are confusing. The engine group report the "engine," so-called, can't be the
> engine. It was thought for a while that it might be a rocket, but
> since both ends are, and always were, wide open, it can't possibly be a rocket. The radio experts of the Signal Corps agree that
> some of the equipment is an immeasurably advanced type of
> radio apparatus, but the design is so advanced that it is futile
> to study it. It can't be reproduced, and involves principles evidently **several centuries ahead** of the knowledge of 1920—so advanced that the missing, intermediate steps are too many to be
> bridged.

Answer (score 8):

As user14111 details, the original was written in 1948. However, an updated version of that editorial was published in the May 1968 issue of Analog SF magazine, and may be the version you're thinking of.

Specifically, the editorial was titled "Prophecy", and differs from the original in a number of ways:

1) An explanation for the appearance of the drone was provided. It was a reconnaissance drone monitoring a Chinese nuclear test, and got a little too close to the blast, thereby both getting thrown back in time (a classic plot device) and also getting irradiated, which explains the radioactivity of the vehicle. Appearing in the past, it attempted to return to its normal landing site, and getting no communication reverted to an emergency protocol. In this version, the unnamed Army Air Force base became either Guam or Wake Island - my memory fails me here.(EDIT - It's Dayton, Ohio. Those exotic islands all sound the same to me. END EDIT)

2) As a further puzzlement to the 1920's boffins, various electronics boxes in the bird bear the logos of well-known manufacturers such as Westinghouse and GE.

3) Since the drone originates in the late 60's, it incorporates ICs (although puny by today's standards), and Campbell comments on both the difficulty of detecting the impurity levels responsible for the chips' functioning, and the difficulty of monitoring such operation, since the oscilloscopes of the day were simply too slow to pick up logic signals. (As a side note, my father got his physics doctorate in the 30s, and recalls how one of his coworkers was the envy of the lab - he had a scope with a 1 MHz bandwidth. So 1920's instrumentation was much less capable.)

Comment: I can't find it online. I've expanded my answer.

Comment: I looked up that May1968 editorial. The drone from 1968 ends up in Dayton in 1930: "Suppose that one of those drone reconnaisance planes we send over China when the Reds hold one of their bomb tests gets kicked slidewise in Time, and winds up making a deadstick landing on the Army Air Corps research station at Dayton, Ohio, in 1930." Your recollections are pretty good: "But it's quickly found that many components have well-known U. S. manufacturer's nameplates. General Electric, Bendix, Westinghouse, Western Electric--it's clearly an American product."

Comment: @user14111 Thanks for the correction. I've edited.

Comment: The 1920s folks do find out one useful thing:  "[...] the secret of making good, small, high-resistance electronic resistors.  The chemists and physicists did crack that one, and it's the answer to an electronicist's prayers; the tiny resistors are not wound with sub-microscopic resistance wire, as was at first believed — they're little ceramic tubes filled with a composition of clay and graphite which is such an extremely bad conductor that it does the job beautifully. By varying the composition, reactors of a standard size can range from 1Ω to 1MΩ."