# Editorial? from an SF Anthology: Radio controlled drone aircraft goes back in time to WWII

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

This was actually an article in an SF Anthology probably Analog or Amazing Stories. It involved a discussion of modern technology and comparing it with earlier electronics. The one piece I recall clearly is that of a remote controlled light drone aircraft being transported somehow back to the 1940's.
It lands automatically at an airfield and much is made of the confusion of how this could happen without a pilot. They would be pouring aviation fuel into the wave-guide of the planes communication systems and if they tried to reverse engineer the circuitry they would only get as far as the integrated circuits and be confused. They would remove the tops of the plastic encapsulations and discover slabs of crystalline material.

This was a very interesting article that I would love to read again.
I apologise in advance if this is considered to be off topic.

Comment: I am very pleased with the answers given so far. I have downloaded and read 'No copying allowed' and although it is VERY similar to the piece I recall It did not contain the word 'drone' that I am certain was contained in it. From this I conclude that it must be the later work 'Prophecy' I will attempt to obtain the May 1968 edition of Analog, I am 95% certain that this will be the correct answer.

Comment: OK I have just read 'Prophecy' and it was very close. I have chosen it is the correct answer. If anyone knows of another variation of this please let me know. Thanks for the prompt result.

Comment: Did you find a copy of "Prophecy" online? Where?

Comment: Hi, User14111. I found it in a PDF of Analog May 1968, even though it is 49 years old I am always paranoid that someone will abuse any link and suddenly the site has vanished or been emptied. I am currently downloading the entire contents of this site. The link follows, it has been modified so you can't just click on it. http://www.jluminist.org/jarchives/SF/AN.htm, remove the 10th letter of the alphabet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[John W. Campbell, Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_W._Campbell) wrote not one but two editorials for "Astoundalog" on the theme of a drone aircraft slipping back in time and baffling the engineers and scientists of the past.

The first one was ["No Copying Allowed"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?66716), which originally appeared in [*Astounding Science Fiction*, November 1948](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?66716), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v42n03_1948-11_cape1736); it has been reprinted several times, including in Campbell's [*Collected Editorials from Analog*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?292986) (selected by [Harry Harrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Harrison_(writer))), also available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/collectededitori01camp#page/60/mode/2up). This one is about a "modern" (1948) vehicle landing in 1920:

> Let's first consider this situation: Time: About 1920. Place: An American Army Air Base. Action: High overhead a small airplane tears across the sky with a high, thin whistle. Ground observers, after tracking it for a minute or so—during which time it has passed out of sight—report incredulously that it was doing
> between nine hundred fifty and one thousand miles per hour. It circles back, slows abruptly as the whistle dies out, and makes a hot, deadstick landing. Investigators reach the cornfield where it landed, and find it ninety percent intact—and one hundred percent impossible. Swept-back wings, no tail, automatic control equipment of incredibly advanced design, are all understandable in so far as function intended goes. But the metal alloys used make no sense to the metallurgists when they go to work on them. The "engine," moreover, is simply, starkly insane. The only indication of anything that might remotely be considered an engine is a single, open tube—really open; open at both ends. But the empty fuel tank had tubes leading into some sort of small jets in that pipe. The athodyd being unheard of in 1920, the thing is senseless. Filling the fuel tanks simply causes a hot fire that must be extinguished quickly to prevent burning out the tube. The fact that this is a guided missile intended for launching from a four-hundred-mile-an-hour bomber makes the situation a little difficult for the 1920 technologists; the athodyd won't start functioning below two hundred fifty m.p.h., and nothing on Earth could reach that speed in 1920.

Campbell's updated version of that theme, ["Prophecy"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1247877), which appeared in [*Analog Science Fiction/Science Fact*, May 1968](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56808+c) and was apparently never reprinted, is about a drone from 1968 that slips back to 1930:

> Suppose that one of those drone reconnaissance planes we send over China when the Reds hold one of their bomb tests gets kicked slidewise in Time, and winds up making a deadstick landing at the Army Air Corps research station at Dayton, Ohio, in 1930.
>
> Naturally, the scientists swarm around it to find out what goes on. It has obvious U.S. markings—but they're modified, clearly not the here-and-now (1930) version. But it's quickly found that many components have well-known U.S. manufacturer's nameplates. General Electric, Bendix, Westinghouse, Western Electric—it's clearly an American product.
>
> But it's also very rapidly clear that it can't possibly exist. For one thing, it's radioactive all over to some degree—and one of the principal radioactives present is *barium*. But barium is totally nonradioactive: it's known-for-a-positive-fact that barium, in this universe, is a stable, nonradioactive element. There's no detectable radium present, and only slight traces of uranium, but half the elements in the periodic table are showing up radioactive! It's impossible! It's not just theoretically impossible; it's known by direct, positive observation that those elements *are not radioactive*. But here, they are!
>
> It also has radio devices that can be recognized as such because they give off strong, sharply tuned beacon signals. At least they do until the most remarkably potent small batteries give out. But the radio transmitters don't have any recognizable vacuum tubes, and some kind of a vaguely vacuum-tubelike gadget may be a radio device of some kind, but no detectable emission is coming from it. (It's a lighthouse tube operating at a low microwave frequency that nothing then on Earth could pick up.) The integrated circuit modules, servo-amplifier systems, and computer systems all use silicon chip transistors, diodes, et cetera.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> In other words, the standard operating technology of a relatively simple drone reconnaissance plane of 1968 *operates on physical principles which were totally unimaginable in 1930.*

Campbell then speculates about a drone from the future arriving in the present:

> Late in 1968, a prolonged and rising grumbling roar ends as a 15-foot drone subterrene surfaces in the middle of the test range at the U.S. Navy test grounds at Aberdeen. It carries markings vaguely resembling U.S. Navy insignia, somewhat worn after driving up through the underlying rock layers. It appears to be completely inert—but the nuclear physics lab presently reports that it's transmitting a code-modulated coherent beam of gamma radiation with a wavelength somewhere around 0.5 angstroms. The device shows a general radiation emission below background level—but *tritium* steam mixed with helium is oozing out one of the small vent ports. H<sup>3</sup> and He<sup>3</sup> are both present—but no neutrons are escaping.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> In other words, we can properly predict that if a standard technological device of the year 2000 were presented to us—we wouldn't learn a darned thing. We don't know enough about the principles to be discovered to be able to analyze it—let alone duplicate it!

Both of these editorials were proposed as (unaccepted) answers to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89241/essay-in-a-sci-fi-anthology-a-missile-from-circa-1968-is-found-in-1940-when).